# Memory allocation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My question is, How to know the amount of memory allocated to PostgreSQL and whether it is sufficient or not.

Comment: Removed [tag:postgresql-9.1] since it's not version-specific. This is a very vague question. What sort of memory allocation, for what? Do you mean cache memory? Working memory for index builds, sorts, etc? Generic bookkeeping RAM? What?

Comment: I am asking regarding RAM

Comment: Please suggest as soon as possible as it is urgent

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer as it currently stands, I don't understand what you are actually asking. And if it's urgent, that's what https://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/ is for. (Disclaimer, I work for one of these companies). Try describing the *problem* you are having and trying to solve.

Comment: @Arun Raut, As Craig Ringer already said that  this is a vague question. About in which respect you want to memory allocation. I mean to say that with respect of processes or queries.

Comment: Thank You @MdHaidarAliKhan. As i m new to PostgreSQL, i dont have enough knowledge on memory allocation. I am asking with respect to processes.

Comment: @Arun Raut, what is your O.S environment?

Comment: So what is the **actual** _problem_ you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I need to submit a report that will describe the memory utilization across various components in PostgreSQL. How to get those details? RAM IS 8 GB

Comment: People here are volunteering their own time - no question is "urgent"! If you want something done urgently, hire somebody!

Comment: I think, your company needs to get PostgreSQL consultancy

Answer (score 2):

@Arun Raut, As you said that you want to know that memory (RAM) allocation in PostgreSQL.

**What processes use much RAM and why?**

```
Shared memory is accessible by all postgres server processes.
```

Normally the most part of it is `shared_buffers`. As per PostgreSQL BOL [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY)  **PostgreSQL suggest to use 25% of RAM**, though often less values are used.

The `wal_buffer` are normally much smaller, 1/32 of `shared_buffer` is default. Anyway, you are allowed to set it to arbitrarily large value.

The amount of memory used for table and `advisory locks` is

```
About 270 * max_locks_per_transaction
* (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions) bytes
```

you are probably safe, unless you are doing something tricky using lots advisory locks and increase
`max_locks_per_transaction` to really large values

Same for `max_pred_locks_per_transaction` - predicate locks are used only for non-default transaction isolation levels, make sure not to increase this setting too much.

No more than `autovaccum_max_workers` workers, each uses
`maintenance_work_mem` or `autovaccum_work_mem` of **RAM**.

Ideally, your tables are not too large and your RAM is not too small , so you can afford setting `autovaccum_work_mem` to reflect your smallest table size.

Practically, you will `autovaccum_work_mem` to cover all the small tables in your DB, whatever that means.

Backends and their bgworkers are the most important , as there might be quite a few of them, `namely max_connection`s and `max_workers`.

The `work_mem` parameter limits the amount of `RAM used per operation`, i.e. per execution plan node, not per statement.

For your further ref [Here](https://www.slideshare.net/AlexeyBashtanov/postgresql-and-ram-usage), [Here](http://rhaas.blogspot.qa/2012/03/tuning-sharedbuffers-and-walbuffers.html) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328861/most-impactful-postgres-settings-to-tweak-when-host-has-lots-of-free-ram